# How can I set the scrolling position of an UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiscrollview

I've seen the setContentOffset:animated: method. Is that going to scroll to a specific position, or what does that "offset" mean?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes. From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset:animated:):

`setContentOffset:animated:`
Sets the offset from the content view’s origin that corresponds to the receiver’s origin.

Comment: did you set the delegate of ScrollView ?

Comment: Sorry, I mistook contentOffset as contentInset.

Answer (score 4):

You can control the animation using

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.2 animations:^{_scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(X, Y);}];
```