# UITableView start scrolling position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView, Is there a way to know the start position of scrolling when table is being scrolled ?

I don't think that I can subclass the UIScrollview of UITableView, right ?

Also, I need to know if there is a method to disable vertical or horizontal scroll in UITableView.

Comment: I have simplified the question, I hope it's now clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your answer on Niall Mccormack I have observed that you can use

```
[self.tableView setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
```

in your tableviewcontroller initialization .

Comment: UITableView has header and footer and the table itself, all of them respond to scrolling, what I want is that : when I scrolls in table header area, I disable vertical scrolling of the tableview, actually that answer did exactly what I want, thanks SamehDos !

Answer (score 0):

- To disable the scrolling:

[myScroll setScrollEnabled:NO];

- > I don't think that I can subclass its UIScrollview, right ?

Yes you can.

- To know where you are in the UIScrollView, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831080/how-can-i-set-the-scrolling-position-of-an-uiscrollview) answer.

Another thing, your question is a bit confusing (at least for me). I am not sure if you are talking about an `UIScrollView`, an `UITableView`, both, or the "scroll" an `UITableView` has.

Comment: I want to disable scrolling in certain direction, not in both direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question.

Do you want to

**keep the header view visible as the rest of the tableview scrolls?**

If so you can make your header view a separate view that sits above your tableview. This would keep it in position as the rest of the table scrolls.

**change the origin of your tableview so that it scrolls back to the bottom of your header**

You can change the contentInset of your table like so - `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-100, 0, 0, 0)];` so that the table view comes to rest at the bottom of your header view.

---

**Also, I need to know if there is a method to disable vertical or horizontal scroll.**

With UIScrollViews you can disable **all** scrolling by setting `scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO` or you can control the direction that they scroll by using `setContentSize:` and setting the width or height larger than the scrollviews width or height to change whether it scrolls horizontally or vertically.

Comment: UITableView has header and footer and the table itself, all of them respond to scrolling, what I want is that : when I scrolls in table header area, I disable vertical scrolling of the tableview.

Comment: Just so I understand - your header and footer views are UIScrollViews?

Comment: no, they are UITableViews which I use scroll delegate to handle its scrolling